# is there an interactive console for debugging in Titanium?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

Is there such a thing as a `rails console` for Titanium, where I could play a little with the API? or even better a `debbuger`?

Or could you recommend me a different workflow rather than having to edit-the-source > compile > Ti.API.debug() ?

I know I can launch the simulator in debug mode and inspect variables and so, but I haven't found a way to write some code an evaluate it, maybe I'm missing it.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tony Lukasavage from the appcelerator team answered me [here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/125319/is-there-an-interactive-console-for-debugging#218418)

> In Titanium Studio, open up the Expressions By doing the following:
>   `Window -> Show View -> Other -> Debug -> Expressions`
>
> This new view should open up in the same panel as your console. Now,
>   when you are running the debugger on your app, you can use the
>   Expressions panel to test and test execute code. Just click Add new
>   expression and start typing what you want to be evaluated in the
>   current execution context. You can do so at any breakpoint, or any
>   section of code you step to after a breakpoint.

As Aaron points out that's not exactly the same thing as a rails console but is similar to ruby-debug and a lot better than nothing : )